# AuthnRequest signing

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'll try to make custom policy for Azure B2C to work with SAML 2.0 identity provider which require all requests to be signed. PartnerEntity parameter includes correct url which metadata defines IDPSSODescriptor element and WantAuthnRequestsSigned="true" attribute.

In custom policy TechnicalProfile I have these metadata elements but none of these seems not to make difference:

```
        <Item Key="WantsSignedRequests">true</Item>
        <Item Key="WantsSignedAssertions">true</Item>           
        <Item Key="XmlSignatureAlgorithm">Sha256</Item>
        <Item Key="RequestsSigned">true</Item>
```

In CryptographicKeys I have SamlMessageSigning and SamlAssertionSigning keys with StorageReferenceId.

Trace logs shows that AuthnRequest is sent, but it doesn't have any Signature -elements so I guess that is the problem why sign-in process fails on identity provider side.

Any ideas how to proceed? Anyone know is it even possible to sign AuthnRequest with Azure B2C custom policy?

Comment: The only relevant options are: WantsSignedRequests metadata item and SamlMessageSigning crypto key for SAML AuthN signing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-identity-provider-technical-profile#metadata

Comment: I tried that already but can't get it to work. Anyone can confirm B2C request signing works and how to troubleshoot this problem further?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just wanted to update that I got it working. Actual problem was not signing issue.

It seems that trace logs won't show that signed part of the request and I thought it was the problem.